# RTP Server in Java with Xuggler

Tags: java, stream, real-time, rtp, xuggler

I am trying to write a RTP Server in Java and I am using Xuggler to decode mp3 files.

The decoding part looks like this:

```
while(container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0) {
        if(packet.getStreamIndex() == streamID) {
            IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(1,decoder.getChannels());
            decoder.decodeAudio(samples, packet, 0);


            IAudioSamples resampled_samples = IAudioSamples.make(1,2);
            resampler.resample(resampled_samples, samples, samples.getNumSamples());

            byte[] target = new byte[(int) (resampled_samples.getNumSamples() * resampled_samples.getSampleSize())];
            resampled_samples.get(0, target, 0, target.length);

            timestamp+=target.length;

            s.sendData(target);
        }           
    }
```

My problem is that the buffer on the client side is overflowing because the Server is sending to many packages.

So my question is: Is there any possibility to wait for the "next frame" other than "Thread.sleep()" because the waiting needs to be very precise.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working inside a `while` loop you can do this with a `javax.Swing.Timer` object that gets called repeatedly with a delay that you can specify. You have to create a `Timer(int delayInMilliseconds, ActionListener l)` and implement an `ActionListener` object that will do the real work.
It will not be microsecond-accurate, but at least you can specify the right delay for your needs.